# gcc compilation time increased due to a windows update

Tags: gcc, windows-update, codesourcery

My team is using `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.09-63) 4.7.2` to compile C++ from within `Visual Studio 2013`.

My colleagues recently upgraded their machines.

Old PCs:

1. Windows 7 x64
2. 16GB DDR3
3. Intel 3770K
4. SSD

New PCs:

1. Windows 10 x64
2. 16GB DDR4
3. Intel 7700k
4. SSD

The compile time for the exact same set of 96 files is:

Old: `60 secs`
New: `104 secs`

Compilation became **slower** despite faster CPU and faster memory.

I've observed this on several colleagues' computers.

At this point, you'd think it's a hardware issue except for the following: I had the **new** PC configuration since `Sep-2017` and all of a sudden, without any hardware changes, I noticed that in `Oct/Nov-2017` my compilation speed drastically slowed.

Therefore, I think it's a windows update that caused this issue.

**QUESTION**

How can I definitively deduce the cause for this slowdown?

**CLARIFICATION #1**

I don't mean that my compilation slows DURING a Windows Update. I mean that some windows update that occurred in the past causes my compilation to slow down.

**UPDATE #1**

I am using a blank `.cpp` file and compiling it 100 times and I'm still seeing the exact same time differences between Windows 7 PC and Windows 10.

I'm 99% sure it's a "bug" in gcc for windows. I installed [gcc from the ARM website](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) and I see the same issue.

However, when I use `cl.exe` to compile a blank file 100 times, it only takes 5 secs *the same as gcc on Windows 7 and on older Windows 10 (Oct/Nov-ish)*

My test script is:

```
set GCC_EXE="C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2017-q4-major\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"
set startTime=%time%
echo off
%GCC_EXE% -c "empty.cpp" -o ".\empty.obj"
%GCC_EXE% -c "empty.cpp" -o ".\empty.obj"
%GCC_EXE% -c "empty.cpp" -o ".\empty.obj"
...
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate the patch didn't come out until `2018` and I noticed the slowdown in `Oct/Nov` but I will uninstall it to be sure and test again.

Comment: Try setting the internet connection to "metered" so W10 update does not run automatically?  You did check Task Manager to look for something spiking CPU use, right?

Comment: @DaveS sorry misphrased my question.

Comment: Ah.  You did check Task Manager though, right?  If a rogue process is spiking CPU then that will slow down compilation.  Another thing is to exempt the folder(s) from Windows Defender  (or whatever AV you're using) so it doesn't grab every file and scan it.

Comment: @DaveS there's nothing taking up CPU.

Comment: Maybe an [ETW trace](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/uiforetw-windows-performance-made-easier/) would shed some light? Though you risk spending a significant amount of time tracing something that's out of your control (i.e. Windows components).

Comment: To narrow the problem, you might want to revert gccc version until you see same timings. BTW, *usually* gcc is slower when it's doing more optimization and faster binaries. Also if it's about gcc being slower to compile, it might about a certain type of code, thus you might want to do benchmark tests on different codes and see the impact on time. And in the end, why not updating gcc and visual studio ? This might have been corrected in a more recent version. c/c++ toolset had undergone many updates in VS2017. MS has really awaken on this topic.

Comment: @Soleil my benchmarking is done using blank `.cpp` file; I'll emphasize that in my question.

Comment: BTW, you can profile your compiler with the Intel compiler tool Adviser. But it's good to have sources of gcc, but you can work on a release version.

Comment: @Adrian I understood that with the blank file, you got almost similar timings (diff of 5s).

Comment: @Soleil that's with `cl.exe`, not `gcc`

Comment: @Adrian, why not reverting to an older windows version to rule out the 'update' ? Take an enterprise edition, you can disable any update in 'group policy'.

Comment: @Adrian OK I got it.about `cl.exe`. The best is definitely to profile your code performance with Advisor. You will know which code of gcc (or outside gcc) is taking time.

Comment: @Soleil according to `Process Monitor`, `gcc` calls `cc1plus.exe` and `as.exe`. I created scripts for each of these executables and timed them; `cc1plus` takes `24 secs` and `as` takes `6 secs` while calling `gcc` takes `43 secs`. Calling `cl.exe` takes 5 secs.

Comment: @Soleil I'm going to do the windows rollback next. Unfortunately, there's some updates in Windows 10 that you're not allowed to uninstall like `KB4078408` so I need to reinstall Win10.

Comment: @Soleil what's `Advisor`?

Comment: If you're compiling a blank file then GCC will use very little CPU time internally, so what you're measuring is the load and link times for the GCC binaries themselves. Factors that might affect this: AV checkers, disk encryption, memory utilisation, the size of the DLLs GCC loads, and general OS.

Comment: What does `gcc -time` or `gcc -Q` say?

Comment: @ams "fatal error: no input files"

Comment: @Adrian well, obviously I mean to use those options in addition to the other ones.

Comment: @ams it's not disk: the file is blank so once I compile it once, everything is in RAM.

Comment: @Adrian if gcc took even 5s on Linux I'd be horrified. On Windows, even `cl` takes that long .... all bets are off.

Comment: @ams what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168754/discussion-between-ams-and-adrian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Defender scans the GCC binaries repeatedly during the build.

Disabling "Real time protection" solves the problem.

Also, adding the folder, where the executable resides, to Exclusion list works.

Comment: It technically `solves the problem`. Another solution is to pass all `.cpp` with same flags to one call of `gcc`